# Scale and center div to fit on all screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scale and center this `div` element to look good on all screens. I tried `height:x%` but it doesn't work. Only scaling it with `px` works. Any ideas why?

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}


div {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

     
        <div>
            <h1>Sample</h1>
        </div>
            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try **removing** ```height: 100px``` from div and also change ```display: block``` **to** ```display: flex``` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the global reset `* { margin: 0; margin: 0; }` to reset the margin and padding of all element and set `width` and `height` of the body respectively `100vw` and `100vh` this will allow the body to expand and take all the space visible inside of your browser.

after that you can also set the `width` and `height` of the `div` to `100%` for each to take all spaces ans set the `display` property to `flex` to use the [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) layout and set `align-items:center;` and `justify-content: center;` this will put all element which are in the `div` in the center of the screen

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}


div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Sample</h1>
</div>
```